# Bypassing speech recognition in Amazon AVS

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-voice-service, amazon-echo

As I understand AVS you send an audio clip to the API which is parsed for speech recognition and then interprets that text and gives you some result based on what you asked.

What I want to do is make kind of a cli version of Alexa where you type in what you would normally say out loud to Amazon echo.

So what I'm wondering if there is some way to bypass the speech recognition step using some amazon api so I can just send the text.

I thought about implementing the ai myself but it would be nice to use all the available skills for Alexa.

Answer (score 0):

No chance.

For your own skills you can do that by calling them directly. Finally it's a simple HTTPS call with a JSON Payload. But it's not possible for other skills except the owner publish is as HTTP Endpoint.

But you have to handle also the user sessions etc.

For a "CLI - Echo" have a look at the different Bot Frameworks. Most of the Companies with an Alexa App have also a documented REST Backend which you can use directly. See Twitter, Facebook etc.